# combining two filter functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I'd like to combine two filter functions I'm using to select a few elements in a table. my code looks like this:

```
a = $('table td').filter(function(index) {
    return index >= number1
}); 
                        
b = $('table td').filter(function(index) {
    return index < number2
});
                        
merge = $.merge(a, b);
```

The elements from `a` have to be first and in one row. so if `a` returns 3 elements they have to be in one row, follow by the elements from `b`. how can I achieve that? can I combine the filter functions from above?

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example of your code ?

Comment: Can you include an example source and expected results (maybe multiple examples of expected results).

Comment: It's unclear what "*and in one row*" means - sounds like you want `merge = [ a, b ]` but it's very unclear.

Comment: Explain what you expect merge to accomplish. It would not merge the conditions into one, or even the filter calls. What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Following the question title "combine two filters" literally, would give you `$("table td").filter(function(idx) { return idx >= number1 && idx < number2 });` but doubt that's what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

you better use `.slice` method instead of filters, in a way like:

```
list = $('table td')
merge = [...list.slice(number1), ... list.slice(0, number2)]
```

or if you really want to use filter then:

```
list = $('table td')
merge = list.filter((item, i) => (i >= number1 || i < number2)  )
```